# Window manager with wayland?

Tags: window-manager, wayland

I was wondering if there is a up-to-date list with the common window managers and their status with Wayland, i.e. what is working, what is not, and how usable they are (especially Gnome and KDE). I only know that there were some problems with KDE and Wayland in november (KDE 5.5), but I do not know the current status both for KDE and Gnome. Is there a list for both (and others, not so well-known?)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Just wanted to point out that KDE and GNOME are desktop environments, not window managers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official list, so you'll have to monitor each project's announced support for Wayland. For example, Gnome 3.20's [release notes](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.20/).

Answer (score 0):

Gnome and KDE are desktop environments which support Wayland.
There is Sway as window manager which supports Wayland. Sway is an i3 compatible window manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are wayland compositors and they act like Xorg window Managers. Some examples are [riverwm](https://github.com/riverwm/river), [Hyprland](https://github.com/hyprwm/Hyprland), [Sway](https://github.com/swaywm/sway), [Weston](https://github.com/wayland-project/weston) to name a few...